# “to consider something/someone as something/someone” in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

I am trying to find a German expression for *to consider st/sb as st/sb*, e.g., as in:

> I consider him as my best friend.

I’ve looked up some English–German dictionaries for the expression in German, but the results that I’ve found were not satisfying. For example, in Collinsdictionary.com, I found as a translation *jdn/etw für etw halten* and as an example for it:

> Ich habe das Bild für ein Original gehalten.

However, this rather means *I thought* than *I consider* or *I regard,* i.e.:

> I thought the picture was an original.

So I want to ask here that what is the German equivalent of the English expression *to consider something/someone as something/someone?*

Comment: Thanks for improving and clarifying your question. I edited your question somewhat further to be more concise and re-included the example as it clarifies what you want. I also purged the comments as they should not apply anymore and we can restart afresh.

Answer (score 8):

The closest match is:

> jmd./etw. betrachten als

*Betrachten* can also be used in most other contexts for *consider* as *Consider the following example* -> *Betrachten wir das nächste Besipiel*.

Your example:

> Ich betrachte ihn als meinen besten Freund.

*Halten* is a more common substitute, but having a lot of other meanings as well, the context must resolve ambiguities.